# Talend: How to filter data based on datatype using tFilter_Row?

Tags: data-warehouse, talend

I have a 400 columns in excel sheet for which i want to filer the incorrect data based on given datatype in Talend, currently i am trying with tFilterRow but i am unable to do it.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you provide a specific example and some sample data from a column, on which you want to filter ?

Comment: if for suppose the first column data type is integer and the input is as follows: 1)23--->okay  
 2)23.33--->reject, as this is a excel sheet and user will enter data and since there are 400 columns for me it is getting as a big task to validate all columns

Comment: check tSchemaComplianceCheck component

Comment: Thanks tschema component is working for me

Answer (score 1):

tSchemaComplianceCheck component is used to check the input data against another schema. Non compliant records can be rejected from this component. This component not only checks the data types but also checks the size of the columns.